# quickly deploy spring applications

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm having an annoying time waiting for tomcat to take approximately 10-20 seconds to redeploy every time I make a change to the source code.

Do you know a way to speed up the redeployment process other than using JRebel because I don't want to pay for that. Tomcat is too slow. I have heard about using jetty but I'm having trouble booting a spring application to it.

I have heard about Spring Boot. Does this make the redeployment process faster? if so how?

Comment: You seems to be confused and asking too many things. Jetty + Maven + Spring works fine. What have you tried so far? If you want ppl to help you please post what you have tried and what error are you getting. Spring boot is another thing but its not really related to your original question.

Comment: A 10 second wait is too long? High standards. My deployment to Tomcat takes 30-60 secs and I find that reasonable

Comment: Don't know why you guys are down voting me. Its an open ended question where I was instigating some discussion.

Well my spring application just won't work with jetty. It won't load my applicationContext beans and doesn't seem to resolve the request mappings I have in my controller. I think its not picking up the class files. I've spent almost 2 days trying to get it to work. still seeking help

Answer (score 0):

You can do hot code replace even without JRebel, just by using JPDA, but it has its limitations (can't add/remove methods, etc.). However it will save you a few redeploys, depending on what you're doing.

Here's a few tutorials
[Hot Code Replacement with Tomcat and Eclipse](https://www.redfin.com/devblog/2009/09/how_to_set_up_hot_code_replacement_with_tomcat_and_eclipse.html#.VYF0A9-jl8w)
[Eliminate Tomcat Deployment Waits](http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/eliminate-cumbersome-tomcat-deployment-waits/)